# Does anyone know why this Ajax wont work?

Tags: ajax

I have some code, some to change the class of a div, the rest to load content into the ajax div. 
The ajax div however, does not load content. Why might this be?

```
<script>
window.onload = function () {
    var everyone = document.getElementById('everyone'),
        favorites = document.getElementById('favorites');

    everyone.onclick = function() {
        loadXMLDoc('indexEveryone');
        var otherClasses = favorites.className;
        if (otherClasses.contains("Active")) {
            everyone.className = 'statusOptionActive';
            favorites.className = 'statusOption';
        }
    }

    favorites.onclick = function() {
        loadXMLDoc('indexFav');        
        var otherClasses = everyone.className;
        if (otherClasses.contains("Active")) {
            favorites.className = 'statusOptionActive';
            everyone.className = 'statusOption';
        }
    }

    function loadXMLDoc(event) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "../home/" + event.data + ".php",
            type: "GET",
            success: function (result) {
                $("#centreCont").html(result);
            }
        });
    }
}
</script>
```

These divs start the ajax code (or should do at least)

```
<div id="everyone" class="statusOptionActive" onclick="loadXMLDoc('indexEveryone')">Everyone, everywhere</div>
<div id="favorites" class="statusOption" onclick="loadXMLDoc('indexFav')">Favourites Only</div>
```

Why won't it work :(

Comment: Look in the [JavaScript error console](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners) and tell what errors you see there and which lines they point to. Then look in the network tab of the dev tools and see if the request is being sent and received correctly.

Comment: Why are you doing `document.getElementById` when you have jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5sPSQ/)

Delete your div onclick event,since already you are manipulating your click event in the script.

Edited div

```
<div id="everyone" class="statusOptionActive">Everyone, everywhere</div>
<div id="favorites" class="statusOption">Favourites Only</div>
```

And I don know what argument you are passing in to `loadXMLDoc('indexFav');` and  `loadXMLDoc('indexEveryone');` apart from that your javascript code is correct.

Hope this helps
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

One obvious problem I can see is that you pass a *string* to `loadXMLDoc`, then you try to access `.data` on that string.